# Overlapping does not work when i set parent's z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index, overlapping

When i set the parent's z index property, overlapping does not work. Here is the html and css:

```
.black_gradient{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg,rgb(75, 75, 75) 20%, rgba(75,75,75,0.8) 70%, rgba(75,75,75,0.3));
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  z-index:3;
}
.img_container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index:-2;
  display:inline-block; 
}
<div class="black_gradient">
   <div class="img_container">
      <img src="http://i48.tinypic.com/wrltuc.jpg" />
   </div>
</div>
```

And [JSFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/alikoyuncu/11jx4j7b/1/) link. When i remove z-index from black_gradient, it works as expected. I read a few topic about overlapping and z index such as from [mozilla dev page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index). But i couldn't figure it out why it does not work when i set z-index.

Comment: maybe you want to know about mix-blend-mode https://jsfiddle.net/11jx4j7b/11/  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode position should not be needed ;) => https://jsfiddle.net/11jx4j7b/12/

Comment: thanks @GCyrillus, it is great feature. But i should use gradient now. Thanks for your recommendation!

Comment: "*DIV #3's z-index is 4, but this value is independent from z-index of DIV #4, DIV #5 and DIV #6, because it belongs to a different stacking context*" [Understanding_z_index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) the *Notes* section.. you can see even though `div#5` and `div#6` has lower `z-index` value that their parent `DIV#3`, they are still on showing on top because it is another stacking context

Comment: Thanks @Mi-Creativity, I got the scene! You can put your answer, i would like to accept your answer!

Comment: @RockOnGom, you welcome, following that stacking rule I could put the gradient above the image, but the problem is it can't have `100%` height, so I am not sure if that's an answer https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/6c1kcrra/

Comment: OMG man you had inline- css on `.to_top.black_gradient`!! no wonder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Here is how it looks now [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/7g57xg54/)

```css
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
.img_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.to_top.black_gradient {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(75, 75, 75) 20%, rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.8) 70%, rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.3));
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img_container">
  <img style="" class="tall" src="http://i48.tinypic.com/wrltuc.jpg" />
  <div class="to_top black_gradient">
  </div>
</div>
```

T problem is caused by concept of stacking z-index, where the child elements have different stacking context independent from their parents, from [MDN - The stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) page:

> Each stacking context is completely independent from its siblings: only descendant elements are considered when stacking is processed.

Also, from the **Notes** section:

[image]

- **Root**

  - **DIV #2** - z-index is **2**
  - **DIV #3** - z-index is **4**

    - **DIV #5** - z-index is **1**, stacked under an element with a z-index of 4, which results in a rendering order of **4.1**
    - **DIV #6** - z-index is **3**, stacked under an element with a z-index of 4, which results in a rendering order of **4.3**
    - **DIV #4** - z-index is 6, stacked under an element with a z-index of 4, which results in a rendering order of **4.6**
  - **DIV #1** - z-index is **5**

So the issue previously was because that children always have higher `z-index` values from their parents because it is considered as another stacking context, just like `DIV#5` and `DIV#6` to their parent `DIV#3` in the above example.